# How is a GPS receiver able to calculate SNR?

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, gps, dsp, snr

I know that there is a certain relation between bit error rate and SNR for every modulation scheme. But i wonder how a GPS receiver can measure bit error rate and how it able to calculate SNR (I could not find the relation for BPSK modulaion that used in GPS) from that. Any help or reference will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modems can measure signal and noise from the calibrated AGC signal.  They can also detect errors in data frames with CRC's.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you how a GPS receiver does it, but in general, once a bit value is determined, the receiver can look back at the value out of the demodulator and determine what it should have been in the absence of noise.

Any deviation from that value is considered noise.

The signal strength is taken as that value it should have been, the noise strength is calculated, then the receiver does the math, and voila -- an SNR number.